# Create a matrix with solution arrays in it

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, append

I need to create a matrix in Python containing a list of unknown arrays r that have this form:

```
r_i=[r1,r2,r3,r4,th_12,th_13]
```

I am running for statements with a couple of if conditions that will give me in output a number of r_i arrays that I don't know from the beginning.

I am looking for a function like *append* that I normally use to create a vector with all the solutions that I generate, but this time each solution is not a single value but an array of 6 values and I am not able to generate what I want.

I need to create a matrix like this one, where every r_1 has the form of the code that I wrote above.

[image]

EDIT: I would like to generate a numpy array (R_tot should be a numpy array).

Comment: You can append an array to an array of arrays, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Louis Could you please explain me how to do that?

Comment: `r_tot = []`  Then whenever you need to add an array `r_i = [v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6]`, use `r_tot.append(r_i)`.  This gives you an array of arrays.

Comment: @Louis I am working with Spyder and I don't know if this is the problem but using your code I only get an array, and not an array of arrays. I get a "list of numbers". This using the Variable Explorer in Spyder. If I print r_tot I get a list and not a matrix. I need to get a matrix with organized values for further operations.

Comment: @Louse I wrote the code again and now it works using your suggestion, I had to use r_tot.append(r_i). r_tot is not a numpy array in this way, it would be nice to have a method to use the array to do the same thing.

Comment: To be fair, you didn't specify that you were using numpy in your question.

Comment: @Louis you are perfectly right, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the array normally as I explained in my comment:

```
r_tot = []

for r_i in however_many_rs_there_are: # each r_i contains an array of 6 values
    r_tot.append(r_i)
```

You can then convert r_tot into a `numpy` array like so:

```
import numpy
np_array = numpy.array(r_tot)
```

Here's a very simple proof of concept:

```
>>> import random, numpy
>>> r_tot = []
>>> for i in range(0,random.randint(1,20)): # append an arbitrary number of arrays
        r_i = [1,2,3,4,5,6]                 # all of size six
        r_tot.append(r_i)                   # to r_tot

>>> np_array = numpy.array(r_tot)           # then convert to numpy array!
>>> np_array                                # did it work?
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],                  # yeaaaah
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```